# typeahead prefetch weird behaviour

Tags: json, typeahead.js

I'm using a very basic setup of Twitter's typeahead. I have 2 different search fields, hence the two typeahead initalizations.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.search-event').typeahead({
        name: 'Events',
        prefetch: '/media/json/events.json',
        ttl: 0,
        limit: 10
    });

    $('input.search-artist').typeahead({
        name: 'Artists',
        prefetch: '/media/json/artists.json',
        ttl: 0,
        limit: 10
    });
});
```

Both events.json and artists.json are formatted as `["entry1", "entry2", "entry3", "..."]`.

I get different results in normal and incognito mode in Chrome. In normal mode it seems to be using an old json file that doesn't exist anymore (I've deleted it). In incognito mode it uses the correct json file, but it doesn't autosuggest the last item added to the json file. I was hoping `ttl` set to 0 would solve this problem but it doesn't. I've cleared my browser cache but that doesn't resolve the problem. I've read in other posts that I should clear my browser's localStorage but I don't really know how. There are no errors in the console log.

And I've just found out that typeahead is not showing anything at all in FF and Safari :-)

**EDIT:**
The results also seem to be depending on the `name:` value. Is that supposed to happen? For instance: if I change the `name:` value to `'test'` typeahead doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

Typeahead *does* work in FF and in Safari. And the fact the without a `name` it doesn't work for you suggests (to me) that something in your json file is wrong, and that it didn't use to be the case, and that your browser is using a cached version.

Since `name` is the key to the cache, that might explain everything you're seeing:

- Doesn't work in incognito mode, since the local storage isn't used in incognito, and there's something wrong with the json file itself.
- Doesn't work with a different name, since a dataset with the different name isn't found in the cache (and again -- the json file is somehow bad).
- Doesn't work in FF and in Safari -- same reason: the json is bad, and they don't have anything cached yet.

To debug, start with looking in the Developer Tools in Chrome (F12) under the network tab, and see the request and response to `/media/json/artists.json`, and make sure they are OK. Then make sure the content is indeed valid JSON.

Comment: I don't see the request and response to `/media/json/artists/json` in the network tab. I guess that means the json doesn't load at all? That would explain the problem like you're describing: old stuff is loaded from the cache. The json file is there and has a structure as described in my question. Is there something wrong with the javascript?

Comment: There is one application/json request which points to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.map. Don't know if that is related to the problem? I don't see a json request to the json files.

Comment: What you're seeing is unrelated. You *should* be seeing the requests for `artists.json` and for `events.json`. I just ran this locally, removed `name:` for good measure, and I see the requests.

Comment: If I use the network tab on the examples page of typeahead.js (http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) I also don't see any json requests so I'm probably looking in the wrong place?

Comment: I was. In the resources tab under Local Storage I can see that the json files are saved. There I have: `__Artists__adjacencyList`, `__Artists__adjacencyList__ttl__`, `__Artists__itemHash`, `__Artists__itemHash__ttl__`, `__Artists__protocol`, `__Artists__protocol__ttl__`, `__Artists__thumbprint`, `__Artists__thumbprint__ttl__`

Comment: It seems that something is wrong with the way the json file gets converted to local storage. I've opened a new question to describe the problem, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718635/json-to-itemhash-gets-cut-off). Thanks for your help!

Comment: I ended up removing the `name:` field since the json file gets updated weekly if not daily. But the problem also seemed that the json file converted to localstorage was too big. It gets cut off at some point (in the localstorage) which can explain the weird behaviour. I'll report this at typeahead.js's github. Thanks!