# json to itemhash gets cut off

Tags: json, local-storage

I'm using the code from this post to generate an artists.json and an events.json file every time I save, update or delete an artist (custom post type) in Wordpress. My question is probably not WP related, that's why I'm posting it here.

The JSON file is used as input for Twitter's typeahead.js. This typeahead gives weird behaviour (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702542/typeahead-prefetch-weird-behaviour)), and now it seems that there's something wrong with the way the json file is stored in the local storage.

The problem seems to lie at the point where the json file is converted to the local storage itemhash (I'm really not experienced in this stuff). The json file is formatted as `["artist1", "artist2", "artist3", "..."]` and if I use the Resources tab in the Chrome Developer Tools I can see that the json file gets converted and stored in the local storage, but if I paste the `__Artists__itemHash` contents in a txt file I can see that at the end the file gets cut off. I assume that this causes the problem with typeahead?

The contents from itemHash

```
{
"0":
  {
    "value":"test10",
    "tokens": ["test10"],
    "datum": {"value":"test10"}
  },
"1":
  {
    "value":"test8",
    "tokens":["test8"],
    "datum":{"value":"test8"}
  },
"2":
  {
    "value":"test7",
    "tokens":["test7"],
    "datum":{"value":"test7"}
},
```

etc... At the end the file looks something like this:

```
"278":
{
 "value":"Luna // The file ends here...
```

There are around 8000 artists in the json file in total and this file is generated correctly (as in: all the artists are there). So maybe it has something to do with the max file size in local storage? That's the only guess I can make, hope someone knows how this local storage stuff works and why the file gets cut off.

For reference, the javascript (added the ttl for debugging):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.search-event').typeahead({
        name: 'Events',
        prefetch: '/media/json/events.json',
        ttl: 0,
        limit: 10
    });

    $('input.search-artist').typeahead({
        name: 'Artists',
        prefetch: '/media/json/artists.json',
        ttl: 0,
        limit: 10
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

This stuff is getting weirder every minute:

In the network tab of Chrome's Developer Tools I don't see artists.json and events.json. Same for FireBug in FF.

In Safari's Web Inspector I do see both files. The file contents of artists.json seems to be broken (at lot of whitespace somewhere in the middle of the file and it then continues with more entries). But when I paste the contents in an editor all the entries seem to be there.

The contents of events.json seem to be fine.

If I add an entry to events.json this new entry shows in the typeahead field in Safari when I reset Safari, but it doesn't show in FF and Chrome so that probably indicates a caching / localstorage error.

Artists.json is not working in all three browsers. It does autosuggest some entries, but not the last added ones (not even after resetting Safari). I'm really going crazy on this one...

**UPDATE 2**

When I type `window.localStorage.clear();` in Chrome's console the local storage gets deleted. When I now reload the page, artists.json and events.json do show up in the network tab. Progress! When I then add items to both files these items don't show up in the typeahead field, but the added items do show up if I again clear the local storage.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the name and ttl properties to prevent that typeahead saves the json in the local storage. It's better anyway, since the json files get updated weekly if not daily.

But I do think that there's still a problem with Twitter's typeahead saving to localstorage since the file got cut off. I'll report this on [typeahead.js's github](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js).

New JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.search-event').typeahead({
        prefetch: '/media/json/events.json',
        limit: 10
    });

    $('input.search-artist').typeahead({
        prefetch: '/media/json/artists.json',
        limit: 10
    });
});
```